# obtener palabra o digitos de un string separados por un guion

Tags: javascript

Tengo una cadena de texto:

```
const serie = "Producto Random-332908"
```

como puedo obtener los dígitos después del guion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con en uso de la funcion .split()

```js
const serie = "Producto Random-332908"

// Esto te devuelve un array con la separacion.

let serieSplit = serie.split('-')

console.log(serieSplit)

console.log('')
console.log('Dato anterior al -')
console.log(serieSplit[0])

console.log('')
console.log('Dato posterior al -')
console.log(serieSplit[1])
```

Comment: Excelente, tenía pensado utilizar los 2 antes y después del guion, gracias!

Comment: De nada bro. Pa eso estamos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto!

```js
const serie = "Producto Random-332908";
const numbers = serie.replace(/\D/g, "");
console.log(numbers); //332908
```